# Take an initializer list or collection as a parameter

Tags: c++

Here I have a constructor that will accept `std::vector<>` or `std::initializer_list`, but it won't accept an initializer list. The commented-out ctor will accept an initializer list but not a `std::vector<>` or `std::initializer_list`.

```
class C
{
    std::vector<int> values;

public:
    template <class Container> explicit C(const Container& container)
    {
        values = std::vector<int>(container);
    }

    // explicit C(const std::initializer_list<int>& initializer_ist)
    //{
    //    values = std::vector<int>(initializer_ist);
    //}
};

std::vector<int> v{1, 2, 3};
C c_from_vector(v); // OK

auto initializer_list = {1, 2, 3};
C c_from_initializer_list(initializer_list); // OK

C c_from_initializer_list2({1, 2, 3}); // ERROR
```

Can I write a constructor that will work for all 3 calls?

Answer (score 2):

You need both constructors, since you cannot deduce a *braced-init-list* like `{1, 2, 3}` - that has to match against either a specific type or `initializer_list<T>` (where `T` is deduced). But make sure to use a *mem-initializer* instead of just assigning in the body.

This should work in all cases:

```
template <typename... Args,
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_constructible<std::vector<int>, Args&&...>::value, int> = 0>
explicit C(Args&&... args)
    : values(std::forward<Args>(args)...)
{ }

C(std::initializer_list<int> lst)
    : values(lst)
{ }
```

Probably don't need to make that second one `explicit`. Also note that there isn't really a reason to take `initializer_list` by `const&`. By value is fine.

Comment: Alternatively, `class Container = initializer_list<int>`. It has subtly different behavior than your code though.